# SQL Server – inserting multiple rows with single (ANSI style) statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I am using following method for inserting multiple rows using a single `INSERT` statement, that is the ANSI style of inserting rows. It is available in SQL Server 2008 and 2012. I am not sure of SQL Server 2005/ 2000.

Create test table:

```
create table TestInsert (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(50))
```

Single `INSERT` statement to insert 5 rows

```
INSERT INTO TestInsert 
VALUES (1,'a'),
       (2,'b'),
       (3,'c'),
       (4,'d'),
       (5,'e')
```

Please let me know if there is any other best way to achieve this

Comment: This insert style is **not** available in SQL Server 2000 and 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL Server - inserting multiple rows with single (**ANSI style**) statement

**For SQL Server 2000+**

According to [SQL The Complete Reference, Third Edition (August 12, 2009)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071592555):

1) The syntax for multirow INSERTs is

```
INSERT INTO table-name (columns not mandatory) 
query
```

(page 236, Figure 10-3).

2) The SELECT statement has the FROM clause mandatory (page 87, Figure 6-1).

So, in this case, to insert multiple rows using just one `INSERT` statement we need an [auxiliary table with just one row](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table):

```
CREATE TABLE dual(value INT PRIMARY KEY CHECK(value = 1))
INSERT dual(value) VALUES(1)
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO table-name (columns) -- the columns are not mandatory
SELECT values FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT another-values FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT another-values FROM dual
```

**Edit 2: For SQL Server 2008+**

Starting with SQL Server 2008 we can use row constructors: `(values for row 1), (values for row 2), (values for row 3), etc.` (page 218).

So,

```
INSERT INTO TestInsert 
VALUES (1,'a'), --The string delimiter is ' not ‘...’
       (2,'b'),
       (3,'c'),
       (4,'d'),
       (5,'e')
```

will work on SQL Server 2008+.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
INSERT TestInsert
    SELECT  1, 'a'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  2, 'b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  3, 'c'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  4, 'd'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'e'
```